# Unmarshal JSON to struct

Tags: go

How can I unmarshal a JSON string into a struct, when the struct type is given in the JSON string. This is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type ServiceResult struct {
    Type    string      `json:"type"`
    Content interface{} `json:"content"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {

    nikola := ServiceResult{}
    nikola.Type = "Person"
    nikola.Content = Person{"Nikola"}

    js, _ := json.Marshal(nikola)
    fmt.Println("Marshalled object: " + string(js))
}
```

> And now I want to create from this JSON string a new person but the
>   type has to be read out of the JSON string.

```
{"type":"Person","content":{"name":"Nikola"}}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, for your type

```
type ServiceResult struct {
    Type    string      `json:"type"`
    Content interface{} `json:"content"`
}
```

you'd need to implement "custom JSON unmarshaler" by defining
a method:

```
func (sr *ServiceResult) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error
```

to make your type satisfy the `encoding/json.Unmarshaler` interface —
this will make the JSON decoder call that method when unmarshaling to
the value of that type.

In that method, you can use a helper type

```
type typedObject struct {
    Type    string          `json:"type"`
    Content json.RawMessage `json:"content"`
}
```

to first unmarshal that `b` slice into it.

If unmarshaling completed w/o generating an error, your value
of type `typedObject` would have the string describing the type
in its `Type` string and the raw (unparsed) JSON string contained
in the "content" field in its `Content` field.

You then do a `switch` (or a map lookup or whatever) to perform
pick the actual Go type to unmarshal whatever data is in the `Content`
field into it, like in:

```
var value interface{}
switch sr.Type {
case "person":
    value = new(Person)
case "car":
    value = new(Car)
}
err = json.Unmarshal(sr.Content, value)
```

…where those `Person` and `Car` are concrete struct types
suitably armed for consumption by `encoding/json`.

Please read [this](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal)
and [this](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler)
to gain full understanding of these concepts.

Answer (score -2):

when you create instance from ServiceResult you could init Content with person too then unmarshal it:

```
service := ServiceResult{Content: Person{}}
json.Unmarshal(data, &service)
```

Comment: Per the question, they don't know what type to use for Content until after/during unmarshalling.

Comment: In question they don't mention that just ask how to unmarshal this type with this two struct and in this case they even could check from many parameters data path or query param or some thing you just think complicate

Comment: The question says in the very first sentence "the struct type is given in the JSON string".